# On the usage of "tell on"

Tags: expressions

1. ‎**" I suspect he must have told on our secret information"**

(I suspect he must have revealed our secret information)

2. ‎**" I suspect he must have told them on our secret information"**

(I suspect he must have revealed our secret information to them)

3. **‎" I suspect he must have told on our secret information to them"**

(I suspect he must have revealed out secret information to them)

4. ‎**" I suspect he must have told on me"**

(I suspect he must have ratted on me)

5. **" I suspect he must have told the police on me"**

(I suspect he must have ratted on me to the police)

6. **" I suspect he must have told on me to the police"**

(I suspect he must have ratted on me to the police)

I would like to know which sentences make sense and grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ‎I suspect he must have told on our secret information

No. Could be *told them our secret information.*

> (I suspect he must have revealed our secret information)

Ok

> I suspect he must have told them on our secret information

No. Could be *told them our secret information*

> (I suspect he must have revealed our secret information to them)

Ok

> I suspect he must have told on our secret information to them

No. Could be *told our secret information to them*

> (I suspect he must have revealed out secret information to them)

Ok

> I suspect he must have told on me

Yes

> (I suspect he must have ratted on me)

Ok

> I suspect he must have told the police on me

No. Could be *he must have told the police about me*

> (I suspect he must have ratted on me to the police)

Ok

> I suspect he must have told on me to the police

Yes

> (I suspect he must have ratted on me to the police)

Ok

Comment: Had the same question. @Sam why is this statement "I suspect he must have told the police on me" is not ok?

Comment: @nouveau , at this moment I am uncertain. It may actually be acceptable usage.  Out of billions of webpages on the internet, there are 5 results for the exact phrase "tell someone on someone".  Not many. Regardless, it may be alright.